# Rename None in a list under pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
Value
[None, A, B, C]
[None]
```

I would like to replace `None` value in the column with `none` but it seems I couldn't figure out it.

I used this but not working.

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.replace('None','none')
```

Comment: Are values of the column actual lists? Or just strings that look like lists? (Try `print(type(df['Values'].iloc[0]))`)

Comment: Yes. got ```<class 'list'>```

Comment: None is a special NoneType objet in python. This is not a string, so there is no way to change its name case. You could replace the None value by something else, but this is usually not a good idea if it is just to print 'none' instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`None` is a built-in type in Python, so if you want to make it lowercase, you have to convert it to a string.

There is no built-in way in Pandas to replace values *in lists*, but you can use `explode` to expand all the lists so that each individual item of each list gets its own row in the column, *then* replace, then group back together into the original list format:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].explode().replace({None: 'none'}).groupby(level=0).apply(list)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
             Value
0  [none, A, B, C]
1           [none]
```

Comment: This is maybe what the OP wants, but he has to be careful replacing None by a 'none' string. This is not always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @Malo for the point. Replaced it with Empty instead of none.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `map()`

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].map(lambda x: ['none' if i == None else i for i in x])
```

Output:

```
             Value
0  [none, A, B, C]
1           [none]
```